# how to move a postgres schema via file operations?

Tags: postgresql

I have a schema *schema1* in a postgres *database A*. I want to have a duplicate of this schema (model + data) in *database B* under the name *schema2*.

What are my options ?

I currently :
 * dump *schema1* from *database A*
 * sed my way through schema renaming in the dump : *schema1* becomes *schema2*
 * restore *schema2* in *database B*

but I am looking for a more efficient procedure. For instance, via direct file operations on postgres binary files.

Thanks for your help

Jerome Wagner

Comment: Postgres is not MySQL - although similar in appearance Postgres' schemas are not equivalent to MySQL's databases.

Comment: The reason for the confusion is that MySQL implements SCHEMAs as an alias for DATABASEs.

And no, PostgreSQL does not store databases/schemas/tables in single files or directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware (as others have commented) that Postgresql and Mysql have [different ideas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Databases_vs_Schemas_.28terminology.29) on what is a SCHEMA. In Postgresql (and in the SQL standard) a [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) is just a *namespace* inside a database, which you can use to qualify object names (analogous to directories and files; and there is a 'public' schema whichs is used as default for unqualified names). Schemas, then, are related to organization of names, not isolation: as long as we are inside a database, objects (tables, views...) from different schemas are mutually visible; so that, for example, a view can mix tables of different schemas, or a FK can refer to other schema. On the contrary, objects in different databases are isolated (they only share users and groups), you can't join tables of different databases.

A dump-restore is the only sane way I can think of, for copying a schema from one database to another. Even so, from the above, it might not be safe/possible if the schema depends on other schemas of the database (it's like you are copying the classes of a Java package from one project to another). I would not dream on attempting a copy of the binary files.